# Calculate angle with 3 given 3d points

Tags: vector, xna, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, kinect

I am experiment kinect on winrt for metro app.
I am trying to obtain angle at the elbow.

normally i will do the following

```
Vector3D handLeftVector = new Vector3D(HandLeftX, HandLeftY, HandLeftZ);
handLeftVector.Normalize();

Vector3D ElbowLeftEVector = new Vector3D(ElbowLeftX, ElbowLeftY, ElbowLeftZ);
ElbowLeftEVector.Normalize();

Vector3D ShoulderLeftVector = new Vector3D(ShoulderLeftX, ShoulderLeftY, ShoulderLeftZ);
ShoulderLeftVector.Normalize();

Vector3D leftElbowV1 = ShoulderLeftVector - ElbowLeftEVector;
Vector3D leftElbowV2 = handLeftVector - ElbowLeftEVector;
double leftElbowAngle = Vector3D.AngleBetween(leftElbowV1, leftElbowV2);
```

However Vector3D object isn't available in winrt.

I had decided to replicate the Vector3D method as below. However the result doesn't seem to be as expected. Did I make a mistake anywhere?

```
double leftElbowV1X = ShoulderLeftX - ElbowLeftX;
double leftElbowV1Y = ShoulderLeftY - ElbowLeftY;
double leftElbowV1Z = ShoulderLeftZ - ElbowLeftZ;

double leftElbowV2X = handLeftX - ElbowLeftX;
double leftElbowV2Y = handLeftY - ElbowLeftY;
double leftElbowV2Z = handLeftZ - ElbowLeftZ;

double product = leftElbowV1X * leftElbowV2X + leftElbowV1Y * leftElbowV2Y + leftElbowV1Z * leftElbowV2Z;

double magnitudeA = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(leftElbowV1X, 2) + Math.Pow(leftElbowV1Y, 2) + Math.Pow(leftElbowV1Z, 2));
double magnitudeB = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(leftElbowV2X, 2) + Math.Pow(leftElbowV2Y, 2) + Math.Pow(leftElbowV2Z, 2));
magnitudeA = Math.Abs(magnitudeA);
magnitudeB = Math.Abs(magnitudeB);

double cosDelta = product / (magnitudeA * magnitudeB);
double angle = Math.Acos(cosDelta) *180.0 / Math.P;
```

And is there a need to normalize it?

i had managed to resolve it, however i am thinking if there is a more efficient way of doing.

Comment: If you use ILSpy (http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) to decompile the `Vector3D` code, you should be able to get your code right.

Comment: thanks for the ILSpy, it helped me to confirm that my dotproduct is correct, however i am still unsure which part of my code is wrong.

Comment: notice that i forget to convert rad to deg

Comment: As far as I remember, you'd normalize the two vectors first, then take the dot product of the normalized vectors and divide it by the distance between them (magnitude of the difference vector) and finally get the acos of this division as the angle between the two vectors...different syntax, but something along the lines of: `v1Norm = v1.normalize();v2Norm = v2.normalize();
float angle = acos(v1Norm.dot(v2Norm)/dist(v1Norm,v2Norm));`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but this is some old angle code I use, return in degrees:

```
float AngleBetween(Vector3 from, Vector3 dest)  {
    float len = from.magnitude *  dest.magnitude;
    if(len < Mathf.Epsilon) len = Mathf.Epsilon;

    float f = Vector3.Dot(from,dest) / len;
    if(f>1.0f)f=1.0f;
    else if ( f < -1.0f) f = -1.0f;

    return Mathf.Acos(f) * 180.0f / (float)Math.PI;
}
```

It's obviously using API specific syntax but I think the method is clear.